# Security Patch SUPEE-10415

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-10415

[image]i applied this patch but getting this error saving rejects app/mage.php i have check all previous patches installed and also compare file is same.

Comment: Please provide the screenshot and clearly explain what is the problem. it will help you provide the solution.

Comment: check screen short plz

Answer (score 0):

Probably you edited that file in past so it has changes which does not match with patch expectation. You can backup and override `Mage.php` with the unedited version of your installation (find it on GitHub or download the code from Magento.com). Patch should go through then.

Check the `getVersionInfo()` method to find the exact version you need to replace if you are not sure. It should be something like:

```
public static function getVersionInfo()
{
        return array(
            'major'     => '1',
            'minor'     => '9',
            'revision'  => '0',
            'patch'     => '1',
            'stability' => '',
            'number'    => '',
        );
}
```